# amcl basic localization

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I am having problems to localize the robot using the topics from amcl

amcl_pose (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)

tf (tf/tfMessage)

Can anyone advise me how to do it.

In advance thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66009/amcl-basic-localization/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to deal directly with TF topic... Just define point (geometry_msgs/PoseStamped, with x/y/z equal to zero) in robot coordinate system (frame_id="/base_link") and transform it to map coordinate system ("/map"). Then you will get robot position/orientation in map. If you don't know how to transform point, please read some TF tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
Hi, thank you for your answer :) it looks good :), Actually I got the position from amcl_pose topic  but I will try the way you suggest. Cheers

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-06-27**:
Yeah, it's much better to use described TF-based method because it doesn't depend on some specific topic. It will work also with different localization code which provides transformation between map and robot (like gmapping etc).

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-27**:
Yea, thats right, I have implemented as you suggested :) thanx :)

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-06-27**:
Ok... Please mark my answer as correct. Thanks.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-28**:
I believe this is the correct answer.